# Additional bytes in ICMP Echo Reply message

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ping, icmp

I am doing some investigation work into ICMP Echo messages.

Below is a screenshot of a hex dump. (Excuse my very bad annotations.)

I obtained this from a Python 3 program which reads data from raw sockets.

Here's a short section of code detailing how the intial packet is sent

```
mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)
mySocket.settimeout(self.__ipTimeout)
mySocket.bind(("", 0))
mySocket.setsockopt(IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, struct.pack('I', self.getTtl()))  # Unsigned int - 4 bytes
packet = b''.join([self.__header, self.__data])
mySocket.sendto(packet, (self.__destinationIpAddress, 0))
```

and then read

```
recvPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)
```

[image: IP Packet]

---

Here's some info about ICMP Echo packets: http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp/msg0.htm

And a wikipedia link to IPv4 header: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#IHL

The IPv4 header is 20 bytes long. This is confirmed by the IHL 4 bit value. The first byte in the packet is `0x45`. This is "4" for IPv4 and "5" for 5 * 32 bit words of IPv4 header. (160 bits = 20 bytes.)

Later in the packet we find "08 00" which is the start of the ICMP echo request packet. The ICMP header is 8 bytes and highlighted in red. It is a bit strange that this packet starts with the ICMP code 8, as this is for echo request, not reply.

The following 8 bytes are a user timestamp. (Part of user data.) This is followed by the alphabet in upper and lower case. (52 bytes of user data.)

There are 28 bytes of data which are unaccounted for. Have I missed something, for example another header in a networking layer?

Some of the values in here seem potentially sensible. For example we have the sequence `C0 A8 00 23` which is a valid local network address, `192.168.0.35`. (The address of the sending machine.)

There is also a series of zeros which could potentially be something like the start of an ICMP Echo Reply, but the rest of the following data doesn't seem to make much sense. Why would the identifier be `45 00` and sequence number be `00 58`. I guess these are possible values but I can't see why they would make sense.

The device replying in this case is a Virgin Media Superhub. I guess it's possible this device sends back badly formed ping packets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We construct an ICMP header. Type = 8, Code = 0. We add some user data to it. The user data is length 60. The header is length 8. This is 68 bytes of data.

We send it to another machine via a raw socket. The sendto() function adds an IPv4 header.

The packet is now 88 bytes long.

If the TTL is exceeded, an ICMP message of Type 11, Code 0 is generated. The data appended after this ICMP message is the entire packet which was sent for which the TTL was exceeded. (Including the IPv4 header.)

This new ICMP header is wrapped in a NEW IPv4 header. This means the total length of the packet we get back has length: 88 + 8 + 20 = 116. 88 bytes of the original packet, plus 8 bytes of ICMP Type 11, plus 20 bytes IPv4.

The stuff which is not highlighted in the above diagram is 8 bytes of ICMP Type 11, plus the original IPv4 header.